# When mouse pointer scrolls off right side of screen, can it re-appear automatically on left?

Tags: mouse

I thought I had seen this before, but I am not sure how to implement it. If I move the mouse to the right edge of the screen, when I move it off screen, it automatically re-appears at the left side of the screen (basically, the left edge is a continuation of the right edge). Does anyone know how to implement this? Thanks for your responses.

Comment: too much pac-man ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that is called wrapping of the mouse cursor.
If you are on windows you can try a tool called [Edgeless](http://lifehacker.com/5254236/edgeless-enables-mouse-cursor-wrap+around)
It appears installing [fglrx](https://askubuntu.com/questions/309169/mouse-cursor-wraps-from-right-to-left-side-of-screen-after-installing-atis-fglr) driver from ATI can bring about this effect in Ubuntu.